# Accessing a changing offset

Tags: php

Ok, so I have this array :-

```
[54220] => Array
        (
            [code] => 54220
            [datum] => 1420542918
            [13148] => Array
                (
                    [artikelcode] => 13148
                    [serial] => 20145920
                )

        )
```

The key [13148] keeps on changing, it's 13148 sometimes, sometimes it's 14112 etc.
So I have this foreach loop to access the elements.

```
foreach ($sales as $rows){
  foreach ($rows[2] as $row)
  { //access artieklcode
}
}
```

But this throws in Undefined offset: 2

What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: So you want to loop through the entire array or just access the array with the changing key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the key 2 which doesn't exist.

What you are going to want to do is do another foreach on $rows and select the key that doesnt match the 2 static ones...

```
foreach ($sales as $rows){
  foreach ($rows as $key => $row) { //access artieklcode
      if ($key != 'code' && $key != 'datum') {
          //access artieklcode
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the index 2 in your array : the shown position is not necessarily the index one
To resolve your problem, you can do as follow

```
foreach ($sales as $rows){
  if(is_array($rows)) {
    foreach ($rows as $row){ 
        //access artieklcode
    }
  }
}
```